# Insert Formula of choice dependent on cell above name

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like a way to insert a formula of choice dependent on what the cell above it reads. The cell above could contain Cat, Dog, Fish or Fox.

For example, if in a sheet called 'VET' cell B8 = Cat, I would like in B9 to insert

=IF((VET!B9)<'Animal Details'!$J$17,'Animal Details'!$J$17,((VET!B9+50)*B2))

This is a formula specific to 'Cat'. I have formulas for each of the other animals which i would insert if B8 = a different animal, therefore I would like the formulas to appear in a drop down list by their animal name.

Any Ideas....?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a macro to automatically insert a formula.

It is much easier to build a little *VLOOKUP()* table instead.  Say in **Y101** through **Y104** we insert the animal names.  Next to each name, in column **Z** we place the associated formula.

[image]

Then back in **B9** we insert:

```
=VLOOKUP(B8,Y101:Z104,2,FALSE)
```

Now when we enter a value in **B8**, we get the output of the proper formula in **B9**.

If you decide to go the macro route, the little *VLOOKUP()* table will still be useful.